# HtmlToPdf taking too much time, while calling ConvertUrl(path)

Tags: c#, pdf, html-to-pdf

I am using HtmlToPdf  to read html from url and create pdf. It was working good, but suddenly from few days back, it taking too much time to generate pdf.
I added line below,

```
        converter.Options.MaxPageLoadTime = 200;
```

which has solve the issue, but still not sure why it`s taking that much time to generate pdf.

```
        HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();
        converter.Options.MaxPageLoadTime = 200;

        PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertUrl(path);
        doc.Save("fileName.pdf");

        // close pdf document
        doc.Close();
```

Comment: The page HTML may have changed.  Test this with a page that you create.  Compare the old and new HTML for the page you want to use.  Consider using separate code to pre-filter the page to strip out parts you don't need that cause problems.  Read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve] since as written we can't give you an answer just guesses like mine.

Comment: We did tried using multiple page, and also simple static html pages with just title and labels, but still getting this.

The problem is in "converter.ConvertUrl(path);" which takes too much time to load.

Comment: Then load the page yourself with a different library?

Comment: Thanks, we changed to different library (Spire.Pdf) and its working cool.